# get all dates dim table which between the start and end date of fact table in fact table

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, powerpivot, daxstudio

I have two tables.
**Fact:**

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-21 | 1 |
| 2021-10-23 | 2 |
| 2021-10-26 | 3 |

**Dim:**

| Date |
| --- |
| 2021-10-19 |
| 2021-10-20 |
| 2021-10-21 |
| 2021-10-22 |
| 2021-10-23 |
| 2021-10-24 |
| 2021-10-25 |
| 2021-10-26 |
| 2021-10-27 |
| 2021-10-28 |

`fact_start_date = minx(all(Fact), Fact[Date])`
`fact_end_date = maxx(all(Fact), Fact[Date])`

I want to write measure in Fact table that the result is the following table.
ِDim table Dates are between **fact_start_date** and **fact_end_date** of Fact table and empty values are replaced with zero.

notes:
1.write measure in Fact table
2.use measure, not new table

**result:**
(select Date from Dim)

| Date | measure |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-21 | 1 |
| 2021-10-22 | 0 |
| 2021-10-23 | 2 |
| 2021-10-24 | 0 |
| 2021-10-25 | 0 |
| 2021-10-26 | 3 |

thanks

Comment: using measure (not calculated column) `SumOfValues = SUM('Fact'[Value])+0` and filtering the dates work fine? without filter it will show 0 for all values from Dim that are not in Fact, this can also be done via code if needed

Comment: Thank you for answer. So right. The formula `IF(ISBLANK(SUM(FactFunds[Value])), 0, SUM(FactFunds[Value]))` can also zero the blanks. But I want to filter the dim date with measure automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried very much with Formula `SUMX (VALUES(Dim[Date]), IF (Dim[Date] <= fact_end_date && Dim[Date] >= fact_start_date, SUM(Fact[Value]) + 0))` but did not receive the correct answer. **The formula was correct.** The problem was **relationship(Cross filter direction)** between Dim table and Fact table, which was **Both**. When I changed it to **Single** the formula was implemented correctly.